# Manually instantiate a Controller instance from an arbitrary URL in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to execute ASP.NET Core (2.1) requests by using path and body only. I'm looking for something like this:

```
string path = "/controller/method";
string body = "{}";
ExecuteRoute(path, body); // this calls Controller.Method(body)
```

Currently I'm achieving this by actually making the HTTP requests server-side. I would like to achieve this with as little overhead as possible by executing the code without HTTP requests. I'm worried that unnecessary HTTP reqs will cause issues with high load.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? I don't really see the point why are you doing this so, I write two solution for the use cases I can think of.

1. If you want the whole request pipeline to work the best apparoach is what you currently doing which is making an http request to localhost. But you are right that it takes more resource than a simple method call.
2. If you just want to call a method (the controller action) in a controller then you should just reorganize the logic and create a class that can be instantiated and a simple method call will solve your problem.

Comment: We have a API (for a game) where offline functionality is required, but we also want verify everything server-side. So basically how this works is user keeps log of API calls that he was not able to do while offline. So if user has 1000 actions pending, I would have to call the API 1000 times which would be very very slow. Instead I send all the API log to server and we run everything at once.

I'm currently calling the controller/method manually, so I have to add code for each endpoint which is not desirable.

Comment: In addition to my comment above: simplified logic is run client-side too to calculate the expected result beforehand instantly. My current approach requires to add code for each API and asp.net is already doing the routing so I was thinking I could abuse this so I would not have to "route" the requests manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling a lot with this problem and finally found a solution, which is explained [here](https://joonasw.net/view/find-out-if-url-matches-action), but it has one problem I'm still trying to solve.

I'm calling /three with batched requests for /one and /two. So I'm expecting to run /one and /two before /three runs and return the response of /three to client.

What happens is that when code gets to /two, I will get error "Cannot modify response because it has been already sent.". So the /first request modifies response the original request (which is /three) and I no more can write the response.

```
public class BatchController : Controller
{
    // inject this to controller via constructor
    IHttpContextFactory contextFactory;

    public async override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        IRouteCollection router = RouteData.Routers.OfType<IRouteCollection>().First();

        // run batched requets one by one
        foreach(...)
        {
            HttpContext context = contextFactory.Create(HttpContext.Features);

            // set request data
            context.Request.Path = path;
            context.Request.Body = body;
            context.Request.Headers = headers;

            var routeContext = new RouteContext(context);
            await router.RouteAsync(routeContext); // get route
            await routeContext.Handler.Invoke(context); // call controller
        }

        // continue
        await next();
    }

    [HttpGet("one")] public string One() { return "one"; }
    [HttpGet("two")] public string Two() { return "two"; }
    [HttpGet("three")] public string Three() { return "three"; }
}
```

I have tried to counter this with changing the controller method to async Task (so no return is needed) and writing the response manually with Response.WriteAsync but that gives nullreference exceptions somewhere within AspNet internal code and I have yet to find out the reason why.

```
[16:12:50 ERR] Connection id "0HLJVLA0U0328", Request id "0HLJVLA0U0328:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnResourceExecuting>b__0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.FireOnStartingMayAwait(Stack`1 onStarting)
[16:12:50 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ObjectDisposedException: The response has been aborted due to an unhandled application exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnResourceExecuting>b__0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.FireOnStartingMayAwait(Stack`1 onStarting)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAbortedException()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.InitializeResponseAsync(Int32 firstWriteByteCount)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.BodyWrapperStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ... await Response.WriteAsync(...)
```

Comment: So we have a .NET core 2.2 API which has this exact same stack trace. Did you ever figure out what the problem was in this case?